# How can I get my Apache server to point to the correct location?

Tags: osx, apache-httpd

I am trying to point my apache server to use various packages I have in my Eclipse workspace which is not located in the default Apache server directory. So far, no luck, all I get is Not Found error.

Snippet from my httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@insurance.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/a123123/Development/Quote/DesktopClient/src/main/webapp"
    ServerName q.local
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"


Alias /DesktopClient "/Users/a123123/Development/Quote/DesktopClient/src/main/webapp"
<Directory "/Users/a123123/Development/Quote/DesktopClient/src/main/webapp">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a [symlink](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/symlink.7.html), by using this:

```
ln -s /DesktopClient "~/Development/Quote/DesktopClient/src/main/webapp"
```